# Passing targets between SConscript files

Tags: unit-testing, scons

I'm trying to get a hierarchical build working in SCons. The directory structure looks like this:

```
code/SConstruct
code/src/SConscript
code/src/main.c
code/src/foo.c
code/src/bar.c
code/src/tests/SConscript
code/src/tests/test_foo.c
code/src/tests/test_bar.c
```

test_*.c need to be linked to the c files which implement the functions they test, so test_foo.c has to be linked to foo.c for example. So the src/SConscript has to return a number of targets back to the src/tests/SConscript so it can construct the binaries(1 for each test). My question is what is the best way to accomplish this using the Return() function? I want the order of the files returned to not matter, so a tuple will not do. My thought was to construct a dictionary with the keys being the filenames. I wanted to check that there wasn't a nicer way to do this; maybe I can structure the files differently to facilitate a cleaner build?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing targets around, you could consider creating 2 libraries: libfoo and libbar.  Then just link those libraries in when compiling the test_foo and test_bar binaries, by referencing them from the variant_dir. Trying to pass around the targets like that tends to get complicated and hard to maintain.

In case you're wondering what a SCons variant_dir is, its a way of placing the build output (binaries, libraries, objects, etc) in a directory other than the source code. Use the `variant_dir` argument on the `SConscript()` function call, as explained [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c3361.html).

Instead of having to create libraries, you can just refer to the source files, as mentioned [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x3245.html). Here is a simple example: (notice that the '#' character means relative to the root level SConstruct)

```
   env.Program(target='test_foo', ['test_foo.c', '#src/foo.c'])
```

Comment: I have a similar situation but my dir structure is flatter: just `src/` and `src/test`.  Trouble is that I want `#src/foo.c` to build in a variant dir, but it's getting built in `src/`.  

My top-level SConstruct calls `SConscript('test/SConscript', variant_dir='build', exports='env', duplicate=0)`. test/SConscript calls `env.Program(target='test_foo', ['test_foo.c', '#src/foo.c'])`.

When I build, I get `src/build/test_foo`, `src/build/test_foo.o`, which are correct.  But I get `src/foo.o` instead of `src/build/foo.o`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @cklin, Sounds like 'foo.c' is being built correctly for src, but is being built again for 'test_foo'. Try referring to 'foo.o' when building 'test_foo', like this: env.Program(target='test_foo', ['test_foo.c', '#src/build/foo.o'])